# Performance Tuning, WebApplication

Tags: performance, web-applications

Whats are the possible approaches to performance tune a J2ee web-app?
Actually the pages take time to load..i have am able to cache the DB results

Comment: Maybe you could be more specific? Is you app slow? What consumes the time, database queries? Or do you serv big pages with megabytes of JavaScript...? Give us some info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching, caching, more caching ... then some caching :)

**And an update 2 years later** ... Message Queues to get workload out of the HTTP request path where it can be done asynchronously

Comment: What kind of caching? Doesnt the webserver cache the pages by default?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the J2EE Web application performance problems originate from the application itself rather than tuning the application server.  I will look into some of the issues described here [Top J2EE Application Performance Problems](http://www.jonathanhui.com/top-j2ee-application-performance-problems) before tuning the system. Fixing design or implementation problems can easily give you 10x speed improvement.  Most default configuration in application servers are optimized already and unlikely give you the same improvement comparing with the code optimization and design changes.